# Understanding Xcode's Copy Headers phase

Tags: xcode, build, header

In Xcode's "Copy Headers" phase,  what is the difference between the headers under the "Project" section and the "Private" section? When would you want to use each?

Also, I can understand why you would want to copy public headers (for a static library for instance) - but why would you want to copy private headers?

**Edit:** @mipadi below explains the roles of the Public and Private parts. However I'm still missing the difference between including a header in the "Project" part vs. not having the header in any part of the "Copy Headers" phase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a public header includes a private header, you have to copy the private headers, but you want to make sure that consumers of the library or framework know that those private headers are not part of the public API.

"Project" headers are private headers that are *not* included by a public header (they're usually part of the internal implementation and thus only included in an implementation -- `.c` or `.m` -- file).

When building a framework, public headers are copied into the `Headers` directory of the framework, whereas private headers are copied into the `PrivateHeaders` directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't understand though what is the effect of including a header in the "Project" section of the "Copy Headers" phase, vs. not having the header included in the phase at all.

Comment: @Danra: When the header visibility is set as "project", it will be used when compiling the library or framework, but not included as part of the final product (i.e., it's used only for the internal implementation).

Comment: The header will also be available if it is not in the phase at all. Importing it will still work. As I understand it, the "Copy Headers" phase is sort of a post-build event which happens after the link phase. By the way, when adding an extension/protocol to a project, often by default Xcode doesn't add the appropriate .h file to any target, and it doesn't appear in the "Copy Headers" phase.

Comment: Also, if this is for the Test target, placing them in the Project section (within the Test target) is sufficient, if there is only a single associated target.

Answer (score 6):

@Danra, if you put your headers under "Project", those headers will be visible to your implementations 'regardless' of the actual location of the headers.

Let's say, you have your folder structure like this:
    /Sources/libAF/AFSomething.h
    /Sources/libAF/AFSomething.m
    /Sources/exec/main.m

If you've put 'AFSomething.h' under "Project", you can use it in main.m like this:
    #import "AFSomething.h"

In layman's term, Xcode will include Project headers though you omit actual path info.

Answer (score 0):

From [Setting the Visibility of a Header File](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Setting%20the%20Role%20of%20a%20Header%20File.html):

- Public: The interface is finalized and meant to be used by your product’s clients. A public header is included in the product as readable source code without restriction.
- Private: The interface isn’t intended for your clients or it’s in early stages of development. A private header is included in the product, but it’s marked “private”. Thus the symbols are visible to all clients, but clients should understand that they're not supposed to use them.
- Project: The interface is for use only by implementation files in the current project. A project header is not included in the target, except in object code. The symbols are not visible to clients at all, only to you.

Comment: I'm still missing the difference between including a header in the "Project" part vs. not having the header in any part of the "Copy Headers" phase.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, usually people have a script to 'clean' the Private Headers so that the public canon no way see what the symbols are. For debug/development purposes leave the private headers be, they come in handy at the development and debug stages.